# Генерация слов путем сложения переменных

Tags: c

Допустим есть 6 переменных

```
char a[10], b[10], c[10], d[20], e[15], f[5];
```

Мне нужно как то автоматизировать процесс генерации слов путем объединения переменная каждая с каждой(все возможные варианты)
Например:

```
a+b
a+b+c
a+b+c+d
...
f+a+c
...
```

и тд
Есть ли способ как то автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: Цикл,? Разве нет?

Comment: *все возможные варианты* - слово **все** здесь абсолютно неприемлемо. Пример: есть всего два (!) слова: "0" и "1". Из этих двух слов я могу построить **бесконечное**  количество вариантов.  Уточните задачу.

Comment: Sergey бесконечное? А разве не 2^n?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch И чему равняется n ?

Comment: В математике (комбинаторике) это называется перестановки (permutations). Я бы взял готовую библиотеку и не мучался. Если цель именно потренироваться и реализовать свой вариант, то начать лучше с математики. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation